# Side-scrolling "map" or "level" game for ios

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I want to make a simple game with a sidescrolling map.An object is supposed to move through this "map" and it should include walls and other objects which my moving object can collide with. I have been looking some at spritekit and that seems like the thing I want to use.

My question is how do i make that kind of side-scrolling map which includes walls and other objects?

Answer (score 2):

The [sample "Adventure" project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/Adventure.zip) from Apple (and the [accompanying documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html)) provides scrolling maps, walls, and the rest of what you're looking for. It's top-down, not side-scrolling, but all the principals are the same. The only thing you'd need to make it properly side-scrolling is new art and gravity (which the [SpriteKit tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) does a reasonable job of explaining).